# pdflatex generating numbered PDF files

Tags: pdftex, texlive, compiling, mac

My usual workflow when editing a TeX file is to call a Makefile from the terminal, usually with the output PDF file open that, after the `make` call, gets updated with the latest changes.

In this particular case, the Makefile contains just a call to pdflatex as follows:

```
FILE ?=texfile

all:
    pdflatex '\nonstopmode\input $(FILE)'
clean:
    rm -f *.toc *.aux *.log *.dvi *.blg *.bbl *~
```

I'm using this on macOS Mojave; pdfTeX version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018). Make is GNU Make 3.81.

I've started noticing, however, that this call is now generating several PDF files (I'm assuming after an automatic update) so that the new one doesn't overwrite older ones. So if the resulting `texfile.pdf` already exists, a new call to `make` will generate `texfile 2.pdf` and so on. This breaks my workflow since I need to close the previously open PDF and open the newly created one, after finding out which number is the latest. Most of the time I'm doing this from vim using shortcuts, which doesn't automatically add the number to the filename, so it fails to open the latest PDF file.

Additionally, this change in file naming is not reflected in the .log file generated after the call to `pdflatex` as far as I can see, since it just says

```
Output written on texfile.pdf (X pages, Y bytes).
```

Any clues as to why this is happening now, and how I can avoid it?

Comment: This might be your `make` doing things. Can you please include the complete Makefile and which version and implementation of `make` you're using? Also, this issue seems not really caused by the TeX-program in question, but by something else, so it might be off-topic here and should be asked on another page of the network.

Comment: @Skillmon Thanks for the insight. I added the whole Makefile and Make version (GNU Make 3.81).

Comment: Can't reproduce with GNU Make 4.2.1. Does your vim-binding just call `make` in the current working directory or does it set some variables, too?

Comment: You are saying that you have the pdf open. Perhaps your OS creates the copies as it views the pdf as "blocked". Close all viewers and try your makefile again.

Comment: @Skillmon It doesn't seem to be an issue with vim bindings because I get the same result if I just call make from the command line.

Comment: @Ulrike Fisher It happens also when the file is not open.

Comment: What's the OS of your computer and is the file saved locally or remote?

Comment: @KeksDose it's a macOS. You might be onto something since this issue happened with files stored in a folder backed up by iCloud. I can't reproduce the problem in a non-backed up folder, so I'm inclined to think the issue here has to do with iCloud's file management.